# Can I cite an unpublished Master Thesis?

Tags: publications, citations, thesis

As title above.

This thesis is only available at the author's blog, though it is indeed a formal Master thesis. If I can cite it, how may I fill in all the blanks?

My concern is even if I cite it, the readers may be still unable to find it, if it is somewhat removed from his blog.

Comment: In addition to the previous answer I would like to mention that there are two types of works: 1. Internationally reviewed
2. Locally Reviewed And Master thesis falls into second category. And it can be cited as shown in example above.

Comment: Sitenote: [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) has the type "unpublished" for this job...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just because it's not published doesn't preclude being able to cite it. You can't *not* cite the thesis if you're taking information from it!

The degree-granting institution should perpetually retain copies in its library, and most universities these days store PDF copies as well. A copy may be harder to track down, but a determined reader should have no enormous difficulty in getting a copy of the thesis.

> Example:
>
> Smith B. (2013), *General Relativity*, MSc thesis, University of
>   Cambridge, UK.

Comment: +1.  Citing unpublished theses/dissertations is quite common.  It is vital that you include the university to which the thesis was submitted, since that will be the place to look for obtaining a copy.  Also you can potentially include in the citation something like "also available at `http://www.theauthor.com/mythesis.pdf`".